# RoR && "coming soon" page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I am looking for a simple way to implement simple "coming soon" (pre-launch) page for my project on Ruby on Rails. 
User should be able to leave an email in order to be notified when project is launched.

Is there such a plugin\gem? Or I should do it myself...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Launching Soon](http://github.com/vinsol/Launching-Soon/) is a rails plugin. It also integrates with [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) or [Campaign monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/).

Comment: Hurray! exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 6):

I hope people don't interpret this as shameless self-promotion but I've just implemented exactly that functionality in a web service. It's called ComingSoonApp http://comingsoonapp.com. Besides capturing the email addresses, it also embeds your google analytics code so that you can see how traffic is building to your site.

Comment: Thanks, Denis.
Your web service is definitely worth a look.
I am still curious about RoR plugin/gem with similar functionality though.

Comment: Not running it any more? Just shows a message about sending an email to purchase the domain...

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-prelaunch-signup.html) is a Ruby on Rails tutorial showing how to create a “beta launching soon” application for a startup prelaunch site with a signup page. You can clone the rails-prelaunch-signup repository for the complete example application on github. It uses Devise gem for authentication and user management, and you will learn a lot from following the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Coming Soon like the other answer, I use a product (I don't work for them) called Prefinery.  http://www.prefinery.com/.  It lets you put up a form on your site (you just include some javascript) and beta testers can sign up.